# How can I get response of this.$store.dispatch on the vue.js 2?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, laravel-5.3, vuejs2, vue-component

My component is like this :

```
<script>
    export default{
        props:['search','category','shop'],
        ...

        methods: {
            getVueItems: function(page) {
                this.$store.dispatch('getProducts', {q:this.search, cat:this.category, shop: this.shop, page:page}).then(response => {
                    console.log(response)
                    this.$set(this, 'items', response.body.data)
                    this.$set(this, 'pagination', response.body)
                }, error => {
                    console.error("this is error")
                })
            },
            ...
        }
    }
</script>
```

The ajax call getProducts method on the product.js module

The product.js module is like this :

```
import { set } from 'vue'
import product from '../../api/product'
import * as types from '../mutation-types'

// initial state
const state = {
    list: {}
}

// actions
const actions = {
    getProducts ({ commit,state }, payload)
    {
        product.getProducts( payload,
            data => {
                let products = data
                commit(types.GET_PRODUCTS,{ products });
            },
            errors => {
                console.log('error load products ')
            }
        )
    }
}

// mutations
const mutations = {
    [types.GET_PRODUCTS] (state, { products }) {
        state.list = {}
        products.data.forEach(message => {
            set(state.list, message.id, message)
        })
    }
}

export default {
    state,
    actions,
    mutations
}
```

Then, the module call getProducts method again on the product.js api

The product.js api is like this :

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Resource from 'vue-resource'

Vue.use(Resource)

export default {
    // api to get filtered products
    getProducts (filter, cb, ecb = null ) {
        Vue.http.post(window.Laravel.baseUrl+'/search-result',filter)
            .then(
            (resp) => cb(resp.data),
            (resp) => ecb(resp.data)
        );
    }
}
```

When executed, I check on the console, the response not show. The response undefined

How can I solve the error?

**UPDATE**

If I use normal ajax like this :

```
<script>
    export default{
        props:['search','category','shop'],
        ...

        methods: {
            getVueItems: function(page) {
                const q = this.search
                const cat = this.category
                const shop = this.shop
                this.$http.get('search-result?page='+page+'&q='+q+'&cat='+cat+'&shop'+shop).then((response) => {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(response))
                    this.$set(this, 'items', response.body.data)
                    this.$set(this, 'pagination', response.body)
                });
            },
            ...
        }
    }
</script>
```

It works. It get the response

But, Why when I use vuex store, it does not work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should return an `Promised` in your `actions`.

Try:

```
// actions
const actions = {
    getProducts ({ commit,state }, payload)
    {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            product.getProducts( payload,
                data => {
                    let products = data
                    commit(types.GET_PRODUCTS,{ products });
                    resolve(data)
                },
                errors => {
                    console.log('error load products ')
                    reject(errors)
                }
            )
        })
    }
}
```

or simply, you could just pass `return Vue.http.post()` up.